# Finding correlation coefficient from covariance matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, covariance

I've been looking all over the interwebs and have been having trouble finding good uses of a covariance matrix to find the correlation coefficient.

For example, given a problem like:

> Suppose that $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is a vector with a mean of $0$ and covariance $P = \begin{bmatrix}4.5 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. What is the correlation coefficient of $x_1$ and $x_2$?

I know that to find the correlation coefficient of $x_1$ and $x_2$, it is:
$$P_{x_1 x_2} = \frac{cov(x_1, x_2)}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2}$$

Furthermore, I believe the $\sigma$ can be derived from the diagonals of the covariance matrix, but I'm not sure how to find $cov(x_1, x_2)$. How can one derive a single covariance from the matrix?

Thanks for your help in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no derivation needed. All you have is to read the covariances appropriately from their corresponding position in the covariance matrix.
The covariance matrix is read as follows
\begin{equation}
 P
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  var(X_1) & cov(X_1,X_2) \\\\
  cov(X_1,X_2) & var(X_2) \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_1^2 = var(X_1)$ and $\sigma_2^2 = var(X_2)$. So, yes, as you say, the $\sigma^2_k$'s are at the diagonals and the covariances are at the off-diagonals.
Therefore
\begin{equation}
 P_{x_1x_2}
 = \frac{cov(x_1, x_2)}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2}=
 \frac{-1}{\sqrt{4.5}\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Awesome, answer, thank you so much! Is there ever a possibility where the opposite $cov(X_1,X_2)$ diagonals could be different?

Comment: No you always have $cov(X_1,X_2) = cov(X_2,X_1)$.